# Окружение/среда выполнения отличия

Tags: переменные-среды

Изучая программирование, столкнулся с концепцией окружения. При поисках информации на эту тему встречал также термин среда выполнения. Объясните тождественны ли эти два понятия.

Comment: Без контекста сложно сказать. Вероятнее всего, это варианты перевода слова "environment". Но иногда термин "среда выполнения" применяется более узко, означая интерпретатор языка программирования.

Comment: Грубо говоря, это всё то, что доступно программе для взаимодействия с  миром за пределами собственного потока — системные и сторонние модули/классы/библиотеки, объекты и функции.